# Connecting to Google API via Powershell with JSON Object

Tags: powershell, google-api

I'm getting started with connecting to a Google API via Powershell. I've been given a JSON object that contains:

```
{
  "type": "service_account",
  "project_id": "projectidhere",
  "private_key_id": "privatekeyidhere",
  "private_key": "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----Privatekeyishere---END PRIVATE 
  KEY-----\n",
  "client_email": "emailaccounthere",
  "client_id": "clientidhere",
  "auth_uri": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth",
  "token_uri": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token",
  "auth_provider_x509_cert_url": 
  "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs",
  "client_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/robot/v1/metadata/x509/termoutest%40test123.iam.gserviceaccount.com" }
```

Does that JSON object contain the header information needed to auth to the Google API?

How would one go about passing this object through as a header if so?

Thanks!

Comment: Which google Api?  If I knew which endpoint you're trying to access and what you're trying to do, I could help.  For instance, 'I want to list all of my mailboxes, hittitng the url api.google.com/v2/mailboxes'

Comment: @FoxDeploy I'm honestly not sure. I'm looking to connect to the API to list a specific organizational unit, loop through the users in that organizational unit, and move them to a new organizational unit. I think this would be the Admin SDK API? I'm new to all of this so thanks in advance for the patience.

Comment: @Heather Did you ever figure this out?